# Using mobile internet on smartphone while being connected to Raspberry Pi access point

Tags: networking, pi-4

I have created a stand alone access point through my Pi that my smartphone can connect to. The problem is that my smartphone disables mobile internet when connecting to the access point, and it does not provide internet. I would like to keep mobile internet on while being connected to the access point. Is that possible?

The access point is set up as following:

```
/etc/wpa_supplicant/wpa_supplicant-wlan0.conf:
ssid="RPiNet"
mode=2
frequency=2437
key_mgmt=NONE

/etc/systemd/network/08-wlan0.network
[Match]
Name=wlan0
[Network]
Address=192.168.4.1/24
MulticastDNS=yes
DHCPServer=yes
```

Comment: Nothing to do with the Pi - this is a issue for the OS on the phone (not unexpected however)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

On Android there are two relevant options you could set in the Developer options menu:

- Cellular Data Always Active - does what you want, but drains the battery even when you're connected to Wi-Fi networks which provide Internet access.
- Aggressive Wi-Fi to Cellular Handover - unlike the first one, this one will disable cellular data if Wi-Fi provides good Internet connectivity, but the phone will more readily switch to cellular data if it detects connection issues.